# Symfony 3.4 Daily logger

Tags: symfony, logging, monolog

How can I config monolog, to save my logger in "daily logs". Now it saves according to the environment. How can I add date to path?

```
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type:   stream
        path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained [in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/logging.html#how-to-rotate-your-log-files), use `type:  rotating_file` instead of `stream`, and add a `max_files` if you don't want to run out of space:

```
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type:   rotating_file
        path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        # max number of log files to keep
        # defaults to zero, which means infinite files
        max_files: 10
```

Comment: I've forgot to add the date will be added to the filename by monolog with this type of log.